# Vue CLI project setup throws ENOENT: no such file or directory error

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to create a new Vue.js app and I am running the command:

```
vue create client
```

Next I am selecting the default template:

```
default (babel, eslint)
```

However, before the setup completes, it exits with the following error:

```
✨  Creating project in /workspace/client.
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /workspace/client/node_modules/.inquirer.DELETE/node_modules/ansi-styles
npm ERR! dest /workspace/client/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/ansi-styles
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/workspace/client/node_modules/.inquirer.DELETE/node_modules/ansi-styles' -> '/workspace/client/node_modules/inquirer/node_modul
es/ansi-styles'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-29T20_47_33_239Z-debug.log
```

I am developing inside a docker container with node 12.
My question is: how can I fix this issue? Also, is this a Docker-related issue?

Comment: Is it Docker on windows? If so does it have the permissions/shares to access the disk

Comment: Yes, Docker for Windows(Docker Desktop), and i believe yes, as i have only c drive and it is check marked

Comment: I've had issues similar to this and it was with the way docker was interacting with the file system. Mine was more about mounting windows containers into docker containers but that was a similar error

Comment: Are you running the `vue create client` inside of the docker container? I've always used docker-compose so would need to run `docker-compose run containername vue create client`

Comment: I am using vscode and an extension named "remote-containers", i believe it does connect to the container and run commands as if running commands with -it option in docker

Comment: Still the error persists, can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall Node.js and then try to install Vue
https://nodejs.org/en/